# why aren't the bridge methods in Java preventing this and throwing an Exception?

Tags: java, generics

why is the below generics code not throwing an Exception at runtime?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ((List)new ListString()).add(3);
    }


    static class ListString extends ArrayList<String>{

    }
```

I understand this is NOT how generics should be used but I thought that [the bridge methods](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ102) would take of the issue by adding the below method which would throw a `ClassCastException.`

```
public boolean add(Object o){
      return add((E)o);
}
```

Note: this indeed throws a ClassCastException if I modify the ListString class per the below:

```
static class ListString extends ArrayList<String>{
        @Override
        public boolean add(String o){
            return super.add(o);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You know about type erasure?

Comment: if it's a `List` of `String`, why adding an `int` in it?

Comment: Using once a non-generic construct like `(List)` will drop generic type safeness.

Comment: You cast the `List` to a raw type which allows you to add anything you want to it. If you aren't getting "unchecked cast" warnings from the compiler I'd be surprised. As for the `ClassCastException`, the override changes the parameter type from `Object` to `String`; a boxed `int` is an `Object` but is not a `String`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bridges (synthetic methods) aren't created unless you actually write the method, as you did in your followup test where you did put `public boolean add(String o){return super.add(o);}` in the code.

When you call `.get(someInt)` on an expression of type `StringList`, the compiler can see that your `StringList` type, even though it is a subtype of `ArrayList<String>`, doesn't have any method with signature `String get(int)` in it. Therefore, it generates a call to the `Object get()` method in the bytecode, and in addition (if needed) a cast, and at the java side of things it acts as if that get method on a `StringList` returns String. Even though at the bytecode level it does not.

If you then make a `String get(int)` method appear, for example by subclassing `StringList`, or by editing the source and recompiling just that file, then and only then is the bridge method generated. Because java is dynamic dispatch, that bridge is always used. The bridge casts and invokes (or invokes and casts, depends on whether the bridge is covering return type shenanigans or parameter shenanigans).

You can verify all this using `javap -v`: I strongly recommend all who find this interesting and want to know precisely how this works have some fun exploring the difference in outputs between this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test extends ArrayList<String> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List raw = new Test();
        raw.add(3);
    }
}
```

and this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test extends ArrayList<String> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List raw = new Test();
        raw.add(3);
    }
    public boolean add(String o) {
        return super.add(o);
    }
}
```